# Review link showing up in my title bar

Tags: bug, meta

I'm thinking this must be a small bug. When I first was able to review anything on the main site, reaching 500 rep, the 'review' link showed up in my StackOverflow title bar. I remember the thrill of completing my first review only to moments later lose access to the review section, falling to 498 rep, because a post I had recently edited was closed and deleted. Notably, the review link was no longer there and only appeared again when I got over 500 rep. What's strange is that here on the meta site, I am getting the review link. It wasn't there at first. Out of curiosity I decided to take a peak at the review section by just manually typing in the address (adding '`review`' to the meta link in the URL). I poked around inside one of the queues, saw the standard "You need such-and-such reputation to review blah, blah, blah.", and navigated back to the main page. It was just a bit later that I noticed that the review link is now permanently there, even though I am over 1k away from being able to review anything. This should be easy to replicate for anybody under 2k. Is this a bug? I've tried this on a couple of other metas and do not see this. But maybe this is somehow tied to how much rep you have on the main site as well?

Comment: I think this is [tag:status-by-design], since if you try to open the privilege page from meta SO... you can see that "access review queues" requires 500 reps... which is actually the same privilege of main SO. The description, *while it can be nonsense in meta since there are no first posts and late answers*, is correct.

Comment: I suspect that the base behavior is indeed that. However, unless I'm imagining things, it seems to have appeared only when I actually visited the review page.

Comment: I think they left it there intentionally. This encourages people to collect more reputation.