# Why is the suggested edits queue always empty on Meta?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, meta

Why is my/the Meta [suggested edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) queue always empty?

I saw this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341675/why-is-the-suggested-edits-queue-empty-when-i-have-suggested-edits-pending) before, but OP didn't have 2K reputation.

Also this state of 0 suggested edits is a **fixed state** for weeks, I never saw 1 suggested edit in queue.

Is it a specific issue in my account or fixed state where users are updating the queue faster than a refresh page?

Comment: Are you talking about Meta or SO, I've never seen it empty on SO, but always see it empty on Meta

Comment: Meta suggestion edits

Comment: In that case it may be because there aren't any, most of the users of Meta will already have edit privileges that don't appear in the suggested edits queue

Comment: Here is one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16244 - On meta there are no suggested edits for posts, but only for tag wikis, which are quite rare.

Comment: Can you explain why only for tag wikis?

Comment: Also, looking at the stats there have only been 1,712 reviews **ever**: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats

Comment: Here is one approved: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12806

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not possible to suggest edits to normal posts on Meta sites (Meta Stack Exchange is an exception). This seems to be [status-bydesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78319/295232) but there have been [feature requests to make this possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223885/295232). To be honest, the arguments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97371/295232) (that they provide more work for ♦ moderators) are outdated.

[image]

Therefore, the only things that need to be reviewed is tag wiki edits and tag excerpt edits. These are quite rare, because the tag system on Meta Stack Overflow is quite mature (only 7 new tags have been added in the past 30 days; on the main site, 28 new tags have been added in the past 2 days alone).

Even if there was a suggested edit pending, you can't review it yet because you need [5000 reputation](/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) to review them.

Comment: So maybe Meta Suggested Edits shouldn't be shown for 2K reputation?

Comment: That has been requested as well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276226/4751173 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256417/295232

Comment: I don't see any answers on the posts (and other related posts)

Comment: Nope, that happens sometimes with feature requests. They stay unanswered until a SO employee answers that they have been implemented, or why they have been declined.

Comment: This post got duplicate flag with a question not related to 2K users and suggested edits queue https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251656/review-link-showing-up-in-my-title-bar

Comment: @user7294900 there seem to be no close votes on this question at the moment.

Comment: Should I add feature request tag so it may be implemented?

Comment: @user7294900 no need, that has already been proposed (see my first comment).

Answer (score 4):

You can't suggest edits to posts on Meta. Either you can edit them or you can't. I don't know the official reason but if I had to guess it's because:

- Meta sites don't get as much traffic as the main site and suggested edits may be more likely to sit around longer.
- Users are uninterested in having yet another review queue to go through.
- There are enough 2K+ users on Meta to just make any necessary edits themselves.
- You can't gain/lose rep on Meta so it's not quite as important that a post be perfect.